# Voice Recognition stops listening after a while

Tags: android, speech-recognition

i am using android speech recognizer and it stops listening after few seconds? What can be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

set startistening at End or Error

```
@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech(){
System.out.println("End");
if(error != -1){
sr.startListening(intent);
}
}
@Override
public void onError(int error){
if(error != -1){
sr.startListening(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: yes already doing but when silence service stops not triggering anymore after 5 sec silence for example